# get tr id from a table with the same class name

Tags: php, xpath

i have a table like this

```
<table id = tablename>
    <tbody>
         <tr id=500, class=classname>
         <tr id=503, class=classname>
         <tr id=504, class=classname>
```

and so on...

I have to get the id of each tr row from the DOM using phpunit...i tried giving the xpath as

```
//table[@id = 'tablename']/tbody
```

and dynamically added the /tr[i] in my code where i is 1,2,3, etc

1. First phpunit said it cannot recognize the xpath...Please help me with the xpath
2. Using this Xpath i did

   $trID = $this->byTag($xPath)->attribute('id');

I am not sure if this is the right way to get the id from the xpath

I appreciate your suggestions here

Answer (score 0):

> I have to get the id of each tr row from the DOM

The following XPath expression

```
//table[@id = 'tablename']/tbody/tr/@id
```

should return the `id` attribute of all `tr` elements that are found. Having said that, I am not familiar with using XPath embedded into PHP - perhaps something else is amiss that is specific to PHP, for example escaping rules.